# Trying to get multiple tooltip/hover text values using ChoroplethrZip/Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, choropleth, choroplethr

I'm trying to draw a zip code level choropleth using the choroplethrZip package, and Plotly to get hover text/tooltips. choroplethrZip plots are ggplot2 objects, so I can make a zip code choropleth using the zip_choropleth function, and then use the ggplotly() function of plotly to render a choropleth where the pre-defined bins are the hover text. I'd like for the hover text to be the "region" column in my data frame, as well as the "value" column. The tooltip argument of ggplotly displays the aesthetic mappings, but choroplethrZip doesn't let me specify those. I tried adding them by using

```
+geom_blank(aes(text=region))
```

, but I get the same result, the hover text is just the bin that the zip belongs to.

Example code:

```
library(choroplethrZip)
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

df <- get_zip_demographics(endyear= 2013, span=5)

colnames(df)[2] <- c("value")

zipplot <- zip_choropleth(df, state_zoom = "alabama")

ggplotly(zipplot)
```

Edited to add a library necessary for the code example to work. Also, the choroplethrZip package isn't on CRAN, so here is a link with installation instructions:

https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethrZip

Comment: might be me but I get (Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : ....) after running df <- get_zip_demographics(endyear= 2013, span=5)

Comment: I edited the code-it also needs library(choroplethr) to run.